Are properties of states of matter true for no force scenario or under gravity and STP scenario?
I have read this:

1-SOLIDS have definite shape and volume.
2-LIQUIDS have indefinite shape but definite volume.
3-GASES have indefinite shape and volume.

Now I am confused whether these facts are true when no force is applied on the matter or under STP and gravity.
The fact that gases have a definite volume(22.41 L/mol) at STP and gravity suggests that given facts are NOT true for STP but if it's true when no force is applied then the shape of liquid should also be definite (as I have seen in a video that when astronauts drink water, the water maintains a definite shape while floating in air ).

Have you thought why solid, liquid and gases have the properties they have?

You should think about limitations of the above definitions, as you could easily confuse solids and gases at special conditions.

when astronauts drink water, the water maintains a definite shape while floating in air There is the acting force of surface tension, changing the shape of the liquid to have the minimal surface. // Air in a box has constant shape and volume, so it must be solid. // Rubber changes shape and volume under pressure, so it must  gaseous. // Water that most of people consider as liquid can behave according to the above simplifying definitions also as a solid or a gas.

In the absence of a confining external field such as gravity, a gas will spread diffusively into an increasingly larger cloud (mutual attraction is weak; confining it to a specific volume requires huge masses such as in gas planets). Intermolecular forces in a liquid suffice to confine it to a definite volume. In the absence of external forces the shape will tend to be spherical. It is viscous and readily sheared even under small forces. A solid resists shearing at low forces. But, is butter a solid?

See also: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45767/how-does-shear-viscous-stress-change-in-liquids-as-applied-shear-force-is-change

You ask multiple questions concerning dictionary definitions that may or may not be applicable to the physical world. Here are two answers.

Liquids take the shape of a container. A container implies an interface. In air or in vacuo, the interface is between the liquid and air, or between the liquid and vacuum. Molecules in the interior feel different van der Waals forces from those on the exterior, causing the liquid to become spherical. Effectively, the interface is the container. Put a drop of water on waxed paper to see the same effect on Earth.

"The fact that gases have a definite volume at STP..." is not true unless the gas is confined. Gases diffuse freely through a volume, whether that volume of space is empty or filled with other gases. This is because all gases are miscible. For example, a small amount of thioacetone, $\ce{(CH3)2CS}$, diffused through the city of Freiburg (which was likely near STP), causing massive evacuation. You can demonstrate this to convince yourself. Or try an organo-selenium compound, to greater effect -- but read Derek Lowe's article, first.


